# 3d transforms on SVG element

Tags: css, svg, 3d, css-transforms

Is it possible to achieve perspective with **3d transforms on a SVG elements**?

I'm talking about something similar with how the Star Wars opening titles look like with 3d perspective. This is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rft762u6/1/) with the desired effect achieved using *CSS3* 3d transforms:

```html
<section style="transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(-30deg); transform-origin: 50% 100%; text-align: justify; width: 100px;">
  <p style="backface-visibility: hidden;">TEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

---

**Update Nov 2018:**

Testing the snipet from the question in latest chrome and Firefox works. Although support for 3d transforms on svg elements isn't very wide, browsers are implementing it more and more.

---

*Origin answer :*

**3D transforms aren't supported on SVG elements**. There are a few workarounds though :

If the svg doesn't contain elements that shouldn't be transformed, you can use **CSS 3d transforms on the SVG element itself** :

```css
svg {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(30deg);
  transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(30deg);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 20">
  <text x="0" y="20">TEXTEXTEX</text>
</svg>
```

In case of polygons, you make a 2D polygon look like a 3D polygon. In the following example, the red rectangle is 3D rotated (`rotateX(40deg)`) and the black rectangle is a 2D SVG polygon made to look like a 3D rotated rectangle:

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px; height:100px;
  background:red;
  transform:perspective(500px) rotateX(40deg);
}
svg{
  display:inline-block;
  width:220px; height:auto;
}
div, svg{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<svg viewbox="0 0.5 10 4">
  <polygon points="9.9 4.1 0.1 4.1 0.7 0.6 9.3 0.6" fill=""/>
</svg>
```

Comment: "3D transforms aren't supported on SVG elements" is an extremely useful summary that I wish I found an hour ago.

Comment: Firefox supports 3D transforms on SVG elements in most circumstances these days (i.e. not in patterns or masks).

Comment: Just a note that should be here: isometric 3D transformations are "supported" in SVG via _transformation_ attribute: using rotate and scale functions it supports.
something like: rotate(45, 50, 50) scale(1,0.5)
where 50,50 is center of the drawing

Comment: It seems that nowadays the statement "3D transforms aren't supported on SVG elements" isn't entirely true. For example, see the following `rotate3d` animation being applied on `<circle>` elements inside an `<svg>` element (tested in Chrome only): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPeyEj

Comment: @trusktr it work in latest FF too. I might need to update this answer.

Answer (score 5):

3D transforms are supported inside `<svg>` elements (f.e. on `<circle>`) (at least to some extent, it seems like perspective is isometric only).

For example, here's animation of `transform: rotate3d` applied to `<circle>` elements (tested in Chrome only):

```css
body, html {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
}

.gAExgp {
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  animation-name: phEs, ipaUyp;
  animation-duration: 4s, 7s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.PwswZ {
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  animation-name: gcRPJT, ipaUyp;
  animation-duration: 4s, 8s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes phEs {
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 2, 1, 180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 2, 1, 360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes gcRPJT {
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(2, 0, 1, 180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(2, 0, 1, 360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes ipaUyp {
  0% {
    stroke: magenta;
  }
  33% {
    stroke: cyan;
  }
  66% {
    stroke: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    stroke: magenta;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Logo from https://rebassjs.org -->

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="display:block;max-width:100%;margin:0;fill:none;stroke:cyan" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" class="sc-htoDjs hCHUAb"><circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="#000" stroke="none"></circle><circle cx="32" cy="32" r="30" stroke-width="1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" opacity="0.5"></circle><g><circle cx="32" cy="32" r="24" stroke-width="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" class="sc-dnqmqq gAExgp"></circle><circle cx="32" cy="32" r="24" stroke-width="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" class="sc-iwsKbI PwswZ"></circle></g><text x="32" y="34" text-anchor="middle" font-family="system-ui, sans-serif" font-weight="bold" font-size="4" stroke="none" fill="white" style="text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:0.5em">Rebass</text></svg>
```

Also available here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPeyEj

Comment: Does anyone else experience lag with trusktr's SVG image? (P.S. I am on a Chromebook so it will be unlikely for all of you guys because most people are on bigger and stronger computers) I have checked the code and found no reason for my device to lag. Unless of course it may be because of the 3D transforms but that wouldn't make sense. Why is my device lagging?

Comment: @Major_Flux- These isometric 3D transforms are happening on the CPU it seems, not the GPU unfortunately. I see Chrome Task Manager using a bit of CPU for the tab with this animation, and there is no JavaScript running, so the CPU usage can only be from the CSS engine doing CPU rendering.

Comment: That's weird :/ how's it picking CPU instead of GPU?

Comment: @Major_Flux- My guess is because SVG is vector based, it is calculating everything as mathematical lines, not actually doing a transform of geometry (vertices), but calculating a smooth line on top of which pixels will be colored. Could this be done in a fragment shader? Perhaps! Maybe no one has succeeded at implementing everything SVG can do entirely on GPU? If that's the case, it is difficult to mix CPU and GPU renderings into one (can have perf issues). https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-iv-image-effects/chapter-25-rendering-vector-art-gpu