# How to rotate in 3D many rect in SVG with a different angle of rotation?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, svg

I would like to rotate in 3D each element with different degrees (rect) of a single SVG. So each element in my SVG should have a different angle of rotation.

[I mean this: IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHCAy.jpg) 

Is it possible?

For example in CSS for many `div` I could use attributes such as `perspective` and `transform (rotateY)` wich different values.

I can use them also to rotate the SVG, but not EACH single elements in different way.

What about CANVAS?

Comment: I wanted only to simplify what I have in my mind. Anyway I'm not asking to write for me the code. I'm asking how I should do. Thanks.

Comment: Nobody can help me? Should I use 3 different SVG? Or to use 3 `divs`? Which of these solutions has a better performance?

Comment: @DisplayName if you really want 3d, you should use divs especialy as the text inside your rectangles is rotated too. As explained iun the duplicate, SVG doesn't handle 3D transforms.

Comment: webgl can handle this just well... But posting an how to here would not fit SO format.

Comment: @Kaiido, _webgl_ could help me, but I should study it (It does not seem easy)... At the moment I'm studing _SVG_, after that I will study _CANVAS_, and at the end I will study _WEBGL_. Anyway thanks for you answer!

Comment: @DisplayName, then start by learning their own purpose. Here you are trying to do something that SVG was not build to do. Happy learning ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido Do the impossible. That's the beauty! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately 3D transforms **aren't** supported on SVG elements.
 
There are a few workarounds that allow you to rotate three-dimensionally by `CSS` the `element` inside: [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476852/3d-transforms-on-svg?noredirect=1&lq=1)
So you could...

- create 3 `SVG` and rotate the element inside, following the link above

OR anyway without to use SVG...

- create 3 different `DIVS` following for each one [this 
  method](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp)