# SVG mapping on a transformed container

Tags: javascript, css, svg, 3d, mapping

im looking for a solution for the following case.

I'm trying to map a whole svg image on a transformed container (most possibly also a svg).

[image]

The origin image (blue) should connect all 4 edges to the corresponding opposite one. And I'm also wondering, if it would be possible to stretch the content of the original svg like its parents container.

I searched the web for hours now and all I found where examples using "transform="SkewX(x)", which is not what im looking for.

In the end it should function like a slider to change the content. If this is not possible, a fade would also work. But still - id like to do it with SVG, so it is lightweight.

Maybe somebody has a clue, or maybe a hint, where to find answers :)

Greetings

Phil

Comment: SVG does not support non-affine transforms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3d transforms on SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476852/3d-transforms-on-svg-element)