# SVG Transform: Scale Y depending on X

Tags: svg, matrix, transform

Using SVG, I'm trying to replicate the strings of a violin - how they taper toward the nut end.  I'm hoping I can do this using a transform (because I have other complex shapes and would like to keep uniform logical coordinates).  But I'm not sure what the transform should be.

Essentially, I want the Y coordinates on the far left to scale by .66, and on the far right, no scaling (1.0).

(In my example below, the Y center line is 32.5).

```html
<p>This is how I want it to look:</p>
<svg width="500" height="60">
  <g stroke-width="1" stroke="black">
    <line x1="10" y1="17.5" x2="490" y2="10"/>
    <line x1="10" y1="27.5" x2="490" y2="25" />
    <line x1="10" y1="37.5" x2="490" y2="40"/>
    <line x1="10" y1="47.5" x2="490" y2="55"/>
  </g>
</svg>

<p>But I want to accomplish it by using a transform on the group element below.</p>
<svg width="500" height="60">
  <g transform="??????" stroke-width="1" stroke="black">
    <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="490" y2="10"/>
    <line x1="10" y1="25" x2="490" y2="25" />
    <line x1="10" y1="40" x2="490" y2="40"/>
    <line x1="10" y1="55" x2="490" y2="55"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a single svg transform. I don't really understand why this is needed though from your description.

Comment: SVG does not support non-affine transforms. You could try a CSS 3d transform but that will make the lines thinner at one end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CSS 3D transforms to get that "tapered" effect (play around with [this example](https://codepen.io/fta/pen/ifnqH)), but since [3D transforms aren't supported on SVG elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476852/3d-transforms-on-svg-element), you would have to apply the transform to the entire `<svg>` element:

```css
.tapered {
  transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
  transform: matrix3d(0.52, -0.033, 0, -0.00096, 0.012, 0.52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 17, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<svg class="tapered" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="60">
  <g stroke-width="1" stroke="black">
    <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="490" y2="10"/>
    <line x1="10" y1="25" x2="490" y2="25"/>
    <line x1="10" y1="40" x2="490" y2="40"/>
    <line x1="10" y1="55" x2="490" y2="55"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Firefox supports 3d transforms on SVG elements. Not sure which browsers still don't. Things change in the 2 years since that linked answer was posted.

Comment: @RobertLongson - Cool! Still doesn't work in Chrome or Edge though. Chrome does a transform, but only what looks like a 2D scale/skew. Test case: https://jsfiddle.net/d6uja0n7/

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  And yes, I would need it to apply to an element group, not the full SVG.  Too bad it doesn't get full browser support yet.