# Equivalent of transform3d in SVG transforms

Tags: css, svg, graphics

This question nicely tells me that `transform3d` from CSS isn't supported in SVG: [3d transforms on SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476852/3d-transforms-on-svg-element)

But a commenter in the replies suggests that a combination of SVG-native `rotate()` and `scale()` transformations can be used to simulate the effect.

Here's my demo SVG:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="circle1" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" fill="grey" />
  <circle id="circle2" cx="150" cy="50" r="4" stroke="red" fill="grey" />
</svg>
```

Is it possible to simulate the effect of applying the CSS `transform3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05)` to `#circle1`, by modifying `transform` attributes on the SVG `circle` element?  What would be the mathematical relationship between the `x,y,z` of `transform3d` and the 5 parameters of a combined rotate and scale?  Or perhaps it's not posslble?

Comment: No, it's not possible. SVG transform attributes support 2d transforms only.

Answer (score 1):

The transform-function now works as it does in CSS but the reference material notes syntax differences between the two and issues may exist, i.e., no guarantees. Hold the mouse down over the block for an example of rotate3d in this snippet:

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 10;
    }
        
    @keyframes transform {
        from {transform:perspective(800px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-95deg)}
        to {transform:perspective(800px) rotate3d(1,0,0, 0deg)}
    }
        
    #thing:active {
            animation: transform .8s steps(100) both;
            transform-origin: 0% 90%;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
       <link href="seat2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    
    <svg id="thing" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150px" height="150px" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
        <rect width="100" height="100"/>
    </svg>
    </html>
```